# JSON validation is not happening

Tags: java, json

I am facing some problem in JSON validation. The code I am using is

```
import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;


String stringToValidate="{'customer':[{'condition':'Matches','value':'nordstrom,nordstromrack,neimanmarcus,neimanmarcuslastcall,tjmaxx,macys,dsw,saksfifthavenue,off5th,bananarepublic,jcrew,bloomingdales'}],'notcustomer':[{'condition':'Matches','value':'neimanmarcuslastcall'}],'daterange':[{'condition':'In the last','value':'6 months'}]}";
         try {
                System.out.println(stringToValidate);
                JSONObject.fromObject(stringToValidate);
    /*           try {
                    Map<String, Object> tsMap = new Json2Java().getMap(stringToValidate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }*/
                System.out.println(true);
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(false);
            }
```

and it is validating the syntax fine. As you can see I am using single commas (`'`) for my tag names like `'customer':.....`. So my problem is, if I remove this `'` from the tag still it's printing true and I want to fail the condition in this case.

Comment: You should consider adding more readable version of JSON data, and indicate which library or package is JSONObject from. I assume it's json.org, but there are plenty of them out there.

Comment: Those single quotes aren't valid JSON either, by the way.

Comment: If it's the same with org.json.JSONObject, check out the documentation it clearly states that, JSONObject constructors are forgiving and they dont need quotation at all.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yeah, it's not considered valid but JSONObject shows some mercy.

Comment: @MehmetM.Inanc My point was that it makes no sense to want it to fail with *no* quotes on keys, but to be perfectly fine with it passing with single quotes, when both are equally as invalid JSON. Sounds like `JSONObject` is validating JavaScript object literal syntax, which doesn't require quotes at all around keys, and accepts a mixture of single and double quotes to delimit string values.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I get the point, but I should duly note that `JSONObject.fromObject()` does not try to validate JSON data. It is a parser and just wants to parse as much as it can. Similar to some web browsers not complaining about the missing closing tags in HTML. OP should consider some alternatives for validating.

Comment: It's creating problem when I am skipping the starting ' from any key but working fine with other scenarios.